# Instagram API media/popular endpoint returning empty list

Tags: api, instagram

Been seeing an empty return from the following API endpoint for about 12 hours (at least) now.  Does anyone else have this problem?

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}
```

Comment: I ommitted my client_id, so the link in the post won't work directly.. but this issue remains.  Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: See text at the top of the documentation:http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to be working again.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1:**

This does appear to be a problem. You should contact `support@instagram.com`

I am facing it too. Here's what I get for a `/media/popular` endpoint GET after authenticating using my instagram login. The JSON returned shows HTTP Status code `200`, but the `data` array is empty / null.

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Language:
en
X-Ratelimit-Limit:
5000
Vary:
Cookie, Accept-Language

```
Date:
Thu, 30 Jan 2014 17:26:03 GMT
Content-Length:
31
X-Ratelimit-Remaining:
4999
Set-Cookie:
csrftoken=c359b115ff344c48dfd1df1108aaf38b; expires=Thu, 29-Jan-2015 17:26:03 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Set-Cookie:
ccode=US; Path=/
Content-Type:
application/json; charset=utf-8
Server:
nginx

{
  "meta":  {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data":  []
}
```

[image]

**PREVIOUS ANSWER** *(Deprecated)*

The `media/popular` is an authenticated request, so shouldn't you be passing in the `access_token` and not the `client_id` for this request?

via [the API Documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#):

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Also, [here's](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) how you get the `access_token` using the `client_id`.

Comment: I don't think that's it.  I'm getting an empty result even if I call it with a valid access_token.  Most of the API calls that require an access_token list it as one of the parameters.  This one, and several others don't and I believe the intention is that they work with either  access_token or client_id although it's not entirely clear.

Comment: My app starts off with some generic / anonymous stuff like "trending photos" (i.e. media/popular) and then if a user authorizes I always use their acces_token instead of client_id

Comment: Ok. You are right, in that the `client_id` request (and I tried it just now using a simple HTTP GET on the endpoint) is returning status as 200 OK, and not an error or unauthorized request in the `meta`. Not sure what is going on. I'll try with `access_token` and let you know...

Comment: Ok.. I did send it to support@instagram.com (and tried to use the API bug reporting tool).  I'll report back here if I hear anything.

Comment: FYI: support@instagram.com auto-responds with:You've reached us at a channel that we no longer support. Please visit the Help Center to find answers to many frequently asked questions and up-to-date forms you can use to contact us:

http://help.instagram.com/

We apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Welcome to a world of pain. On their google group for Instagram support, they've deferred their support to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram and stated that their developers are actively monitoring it. But it doesn't look like they are. I think we are SOL.

Answer (score 0):

Their API pages and developer portal seem to be down with GATEWAY Errors. I'm guessing they are dealing with something at the moment.